# Expending text rotator to work on more than one text instance

Tags: jquery

Here is my code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EoQmjb

The idea is it rotates different text into position every x amount of seconds to make the sentence different. The code was pinched and slightly modified to be the below:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({ 
        rotaterator: function(options) {

            var defaults = {
                fadeSpeed: 500,
                pauseSpeed: 500,
                child:null
            };

            var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

            return this.each(function() {
                  var o =options;
                  var obj = $(this);                
                  var items = $(obj.children(), obj);
                  items.each(function() {$(this).hide();})
                  if(!o.child){var next = $(obj).children(':first');
                  }else{var next = o.child;
                  }
                  $(next).fadeIn(o.fadeSpeed, function() {
                        $(next).delay(o.pauseSpeed).fadeOut(o.fadeSpeed, function() {
                            var next = $(this).next();
                            if (next.length == 0){
                                    next = $(obj).children(':first');
                            }
                            $(obj).rotaterator({child : next, fadeSpeed : o.fadeSpeed, pauseSpeed : o.pauseSpeed});
                        })
                    });
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);

 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#rotate').rotaterator({fadeSpeed:200, pauseSpeed:3000});
 });
```

The issue is it only works when there is more than one instance of the text changer. Is it possible to tweak this code so it can do more than one at once? You can see in my example that A B C is all shown at the same time.

Comment: what do you mean more than one at once?

Comment: @ddk I have two instances of HTML tags where the text should be rotating but it only works on the first instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not allowed duplicate HTML element IDs on a page.  jQuery will simply grab only the first one and work with that instead of grabbing all of them.  If you use class instead, jQuery will grab all of them, and should work.

I'd structure the HTML differently (using spans instead of divs), but this answers your question with the code you supplied.  Hope it helps :-)

**JavaScript**

```
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({ 
        rotaterator: function(options) {

            var defaults = {
                fadeSpeed: 500,
                pauseSpeed: 500,
                child:null
            };

            var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

            return this.each(function() {
                  var o =options;
                  var obj = $(this);                
                  var items = $(obj.children(), obj);
                  items.each(function() {$(this).hide();})
                  if(!o.child){var next = $(obj).children(':first');
                  }else{var next = o.child;
                  }
                  $(next).fadeIn(o.fadeSpeed, function() {
                        $(next).delay(o.pauseSpeed).fadeOut(o.fadeSpeed, function() {
                            var next = $(this).next();
                            if (next.length == 0){
                                    next = $(obj).children(':first');
                            }
                            $(obj).rotaterator({child : next, fadeSpeed : o.fadeSpeed, pauseSpeed : o.pauseSpeed});
                        })
                    });
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);

 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.rotate').rotaterator({fadeSpeed:200, pauseSpeed:3000});
 });
```

**HTML**

```
<h1>A weekend of
    <div class="rotate"> 
        <div>fun</div>
        <div>games</div>
        <div>laughter</div>
    </div> and
    <div class="rotate"> 
        <div>a</div>
        <div>b</div>
        <div>c</div>
        <div>d</div>
    </div>
</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have two instances of div with id rotate1 and rotate2 and call rotaterator on both divs

```js
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({ 
        rotaterator: function(options) {
 
            var defaults = {
                fadeSpeed: 500,
                pauseSpeed: 500,
    child:null
            };
             
            var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
         
            return this.each(function() {
                  var o =options;
                  var obj = $(this);                
                  var items = $(obj.children(), obj);
      items.each(function() {$(this).hide();})
      if(!o.child){var next = $(obj).children(':first');
      }else{var next = o.child;
      }
      $(next).fadeIn(o.fadeSpeed, function() {
      $(next).delay(o.pauseSpeed).fadeOut(o.fadeSpeed, function() {
       var next = $(this).next();
       if (next.length == 0){
         next = $(obj).children(':first');
       }
       $(obj).rotaterator({child : next, fadeSpeed : o.fadeSpeed, pauseSpeed : o.pauseSpeed});
      })
     });
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);

 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#rotate1').rotaterator({fadeSpeed:200, pauseSpeed:2000});
    $('#rotate2').rotaterator({fadeSpeed:200, pauseSpeed:3000});
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>A weekend of
<div id="rotate1"> 
 <div>fun</div>
  <div>games</div> <div>laughter</div></div> and
<div id="rotate2"> 
 <div>a</div>
  <div>b</div> <div>c</div> <div>d</div></div></h1>
```